# How do I prevent my Facebook and Instagram acccount from appearing in "people you may know" recommendations?

Tags: privacy, account-security, anonymity, facebook

Facebook tends to "recommend" your account based on IP and collected data. How do I keep it hidden from people that are geographically related to me? I want to create a pseudo-anonymous account that isn't linked to my real identity in any way.

Comment: Go one step further and dont use facebook

Comment: Just because you spoofed your IP and location doesn't mean you won't show up on your mutuals recommended.

Comment: Good advice, still, I'd like to be able to use it without compromising myself

Comment: @yeah_well, yeah, I know that. That's why I don't even bother... Still, I took some precautions: 1) I don't use those accounts on a phone 2) I have anti-tracking filters installed in my Mozilla Adblocker (uBlock origin) 3) I didn't link a phone number when created those accounts 4) In Instagram I checked "Private Account" setting

Comment: This is off-topic in this community. Anyway, the answer is that Facebook is *very good* at tracking and identifying people (that's their main goal), so unless you go for full-anonymity (difficult and painful to achieve) there's no guarantee of success.

Comment: My main goal isn't to hide my activity from Instagram or Facebook themselves or government agencies they're forced to work with for obvious reasons. It is to make people I know not know about what I'm doing online @reed

Comment: people you know won't know what you do online, unless you share everything you do.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using Facebook and Instagram. It's that simple.

[Delete your Facebook Account.](http://Facebook)

> Facebook is not your friend, it is a surveillance engine. ― Richard
> Stallman

> Facebook in particular is the most appalling spying machine that has
> ever been invented ― Julian Assange

[Redact](https://redact.dev/) allows you to automatically clean up your old posts from services like Facebook.